# using thrust device_vector as global variable

Tags: cuda, thrust

Why does the following code crash at the end of the main?

```cuda
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

thrust::device_vector<float4> v;

int main(){
    v.resize(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
what():  unspecified driver error
```

If I use `host_vector` instead of `device_vector` the code run fine.

Do you think it's a Thrust bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

I tried it on ubuntu 10.10 with cuda 4.0 and on Windows 7 with cuda 6.5.
The Thrust version is 1.7 in both cases.

thanks

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That isn't what is happening here. This is happening because the vector drops out of scope and is destroyed after the CUDA context is torn down. So effectively cudaFree is getting called with no working runtime API connection, resulting in a runtime error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is neither a bug in Thrust, nor are you doing something wrong. Rather, this is a limitation of the design of the CUDA runtime API.

The underlying reason for the crash is that the destructor for the `thrust::vector` is being called when the variable falls out of scope, which is happening after the CUDA runtime API context has been torn down. This will produce a runtime error (probably `cudaErrorCudartUnloading`) because the process is attempting to call `cudaFree` after it has already disconnected from the CUDA driver.

I am unaware of a workaround other than not using Thrust device containers declared at `main()` translation unit scope.